# Woo-commerce edit account shortcode not working at all

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, account

Current Woocommerce version under our usage is 2.5.5 I am using following shortcode inside my edit account page.

```
[woocommerce_edit_account]
```

But, my page shows home page instead of edit account page. Is some thing new now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't work anymore, they're only for Woocommerce 2.1 or less. They have been replaced with endpoints, so you would need to do something like this:

```
$my_account_link = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
$edit_acount_link = $my_account_link . '/edit-account';
```

If the first line is too  long try with this:

```
$my_account_link = get_bloginfo('url'). '/my-account';
```

You can read more information about endpoints at: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/

Comment: I not just want to show link, I Want to show when ever user clicks on or reaches in other words at edit account page he/she will be able to edit his/her account. Will your code provide that one ? additionally, where will I put this code ? i was trying to use shortcode inside page editer but your code will not run there .... any thing more plzzz

Comment: You can put this code in a custom shortcode or in any hook/filter to do what you want.

Comment: @laraib I believe what you are looking for is in my answer to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328856/woocommerce-edit-account-shortcode

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead the native WooCommerce function [**wc_customer_edit_account_url()**](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_customer_edit_account_url.html#153-162p). 
*(It's used in woocommerce `my_account.php` template too)*.

As [*Skatox*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343452/skatox) mention it, `[woocommerce_edit_account]` doesn't work anymore.

You can use it with a custom self closing shortcode:

```
// Paste this in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme.
function wc_customer_edit_account_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'text' => '',
        ),
    );

    return '<a class="customer-edit-account" href="'.wc_customer_edit_account().'">'.$text.'</a>';

}
add_shortcode( 'wc_customer_edit_account', 'wc_customer_edit_account_shortcode' );
```

Use: `[wc_customer_edit_account text="Editing my account details" /]`

Answer (score 0):

On my site (with WooCommerce 3.6.5) this is the code that worked for me:

```
// Paste this in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme.
function wc_customer_edit_account_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'text' => 'Edit Account' ), $atts ) );

    return '<a class="customer-edit-account" href="'.wc_customer_edit_account_url().'">'.$text.'</a>';

}
add_shortcode( 'wc_customer_edit_account', 'wc_customer_edit_account_shortcode' );
```

Instead of editing the function.php or even adding a child theme, I pasted it in a New Snippet using the [Snippets](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.