# woocommerce edit-account shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I saw in this question that is possible create a shortcode from my-orders page, I am trying create something similar to display the edit account page via shortcodes.

Reference: [in woocommerce, is there a shortcode/page to view all orders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980505/in-woocommerce-is-there-a-shortcode-page-to-view-all-orders)

```
function shortcode_my_orders( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'order_count' => -1
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start();
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
        'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
        'order_count'   => $order_count
    ) );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_orders', 'shortcode_my_orders');
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this shortcode to add the HTML contents of the *Edit Account* page in another page. I believe that's what you are asking for.

```
// Paste this in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme.
function wc_customer_edit_account_html_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'text' => 'Edit Account' ), $atts ) );

    return wc_get_template_html( 'myaccount/form-edit-account.php', array( 'user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ) ) );;

}
add_shortcode( 'wc_customer_edit_account_html', 'wc_customer_edit_account_html_shortcode' );
```

You can also put this in a *New Snippet* in the [Snippets plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) instead of editing the *functions.php* page.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the edit account form, wherever you want, with this code:

```
function clket_edit_account_form(){
    ob_start();
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-edit-account.php', array( 'user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ) ) );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('clket_edit_account', 'clket_edit_account_form');
```

Shortcode: `[clket_edit_account]`

Ref: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_shortcode_my_accountedit_account/